# How can I delete or remove a modifier?

Tags: modifiers

I have added a mirror modifier and a surface subdivision modifier but I can't understand how to remove them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the X in the modifier header?

[image: ModClose]

Comment: Ops i don't know why I did not notice it until now

Comment: Hey eezacque, I added an example image to your answer to make it even clearer for future users. Hope you don't mind ;)

Comment: You can also hover the mouse over the modifier panel and hit 'X' to delete it (something I've only just realised myself...) :^)